# Integrate Razorpay quick payments plugin with contact form7 plugin

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using a Contact form7 and Razorpay quick checkout plugin in WordPress.

The shortcode for it is `[RZP]`. Help me use this in contact form7.

What I have tried is in the `functions.php` of contact-form-7 plugin, I have inserted this function:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'mycustom_wpcf7_form_elements' );

function mycustom_wpcf7_form_elements( $form ) {
$form = do_shortcode( $form );

return $form;
}
```

This gives me ability to add outside shortcodes, but doesn't work for the Razorpay quick payments plugin. Also, it gives the button but doesn't give the pop up for the quick checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate a a custom field tag into your form so that the cf7 validation process correctly identifies your required field.  To do this you need to create a custom field tag using contact form 7 hook functionality, the details of which you can find on the contact form 7 [official website](https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/).  Googling how to add custom form tags in cf7 also points to similar answers in this forum.

Comment: I have already tried it. It doesn't work. I have used the plugin for it also to import custom tags, that also doesn't work. The code that I showed you does that only. :)

Comment: the `wpcf7_form_elements` filter is used to modify the output of the form.  Your question is about validating a field as required.  Validation in cf7 takes place once the form is submitted, so although you form modification might be successful it does not instruct the cf7 plugin to process and validate your field.  The only way to do this is to with a custom tag as I pointed out above.  If you have tried this without success it means you have not understood how it works.  Look at how it is done in the code of a plugin like [CF7 Module](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/)

Comment: there is one more way to achieve this and that is to create your own javascript script to detect field completion before submitting the form.